# How to print part of the alphabet in reverse order?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, irvine32

I have this function that prints the first N characters of the alphabet:

```
proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov al, 'A'         ;Stores characther              
L1:     call WriteChar      ;Writes character
        inc al              ;Increment al
        loop L4
        ret
proc1 ENDP
```

I am trying to reverse the string but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Your `loop` goes to an unknown label. And what string may be to reverse?

Comment: Don't use `loop` when it's easier to use something else as the loop condition.  If the caller passes a start and end character, you could do something like `dec al` / `cmp al, dl` / `jae L1` (where `al` is the current character, and `dl` is the lower limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov al, 'A'         ;Stores characther              
L1:     call WriteChar      ;Writes character
        inc al              ;Increment al
        loop L1
        ret
proc1 ENDP
```

If the code above when given a counter `ECX=7` produces the string "ABCDEFG" then the following code will produce the inverse string "GFEDCBA":

```
proc1 PROC  USES ecx
        mov al, 'G'         ;Stores characther              
L1:     call WriteChar      ;Writes character
        dec al              ;Decrement al
        loop L1
        ret
proc1 ENDP
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like:

```
proc    inversestring
;       edx - string to inverse
;       ecx - string length
...
        ret
endp
```